# GetClipboardData is failed when clipboard contains more than 10000 files

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, clipboard

I've an MFC application to list the files in the clipboard, the code works fine if the clipboard contains less than 10000 files, **but if it is more than 10000** **`GetClipboardData`** **API failed**.
When I use **`GetLastError()`** it returns **1418 ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN**

```
TCHAR lpszFileName[MAX_PATH];
    OpenClipboard(0);
    APDeviceReport objApd;
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = (HGLOBAL)GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP); // Failed when clipboard conatins more than 10000 files
    if (hGlobal)
    {
        HDROP hDrop = (HDROP)GlobalLock(hGlobal);
        if (hDrop)
        {   
            UINT fileCount = DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0, 0);
            UINT filenameLength;
            for (UINT i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) 
            {
                filenameLength = DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, 0, 0);
                DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, lpszFileName, filenameLength+1);
                objApd.AddFileList(lpszFileName);
            }
            GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
        }
    }
    CloseClipboard();
```

If anyone knows why it is please share suggestions to solve this.

Comment: Also you are supplying the wrong buffer size to `DragQueryFile`, it should be `MAX_PATH`, not `filenameLength+1`. You should check whether filepath can fit into your buffer first.

Comment: @MarshalSebastian just to be sure: where _exactly_ did ou call `GetLastError()`.

Comment: If you receive an error code of `ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN`, it stands to reason, that the clipboard hasn't been opened. Since you never check, whether `OpenClipboard` succeeds, this would be a prime candidate for further investigation. Also make sure you understand the implications of passing `NULL` to `OpenClipboard`.

Comment: __Where__ did you put `GetLastError()`? Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Per the `OpenClipboard()` documentation: "*If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`... **`OpenClipboard` fails if another window has the clipboard open**.*" Is it possible that when you try to read the data, Explorer still has the clipboard open and is still putting the data on the clipboard?

Comment: @IInspectable the issue with passing NULL only applies when setting clipboard data, not when reading it